# Multi-container POD - Restart a second container based on events of first container in

Tags: kubernetes

We have a k8s POD that contains two containers, c1 and c2. How do we trigger a restart of 
the second container (c2) based on some event of the first container (c1)?

For instance, container c1 is a data container that pulls data from s3 bucket. The data is shared and used by the second container (c2). We want to restart the second container (c2) when data is pulled from s3 so it can be loaded to memory by container c2.

Comment: Did you look into this: [Attach Handlers to Container Lifecycle Events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/)

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am blocked due to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve it using the [`shareProcessNamespace`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/) option.

Take a look to this dummy example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mult
iple  name: multiple
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: multiple
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: multiple
    spec:
      shareProcessNamespace: true
      containers:
      - image: nginx:alpine
        name: nginx
      - image: redis:alpine
        name: redis
```

The result should be something like this:

```
# kubectl get pods
multiple-5f44d65855-xzgz2                   2/2     Running            0          84s
```

Now, if you enter in the container `nginx` of the pod, you can see the shared PID namespace:

```
# kubectl exec -it multiple-5f44d65855-xzgz2 -c nginx -- ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /pause
   51 root      0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
   56 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   57 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   58 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   59 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   74 999       0:00 redis-server
   86 root      0:00 ps aux
```

At this point, you can perform your business logic that can be a *kill -9* or, if you can trap the signal, intercept a *sighup* in order to restart the process.